# How to ssh into AWS Ubuntu instance from different machine?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, pem

I have set up an Amazon instance (ubuntu).  I have two machines.

On the first machine, I set up my account, and I can ssh into my instance as normal:

- I create the key pair, and save the pem file, etc., and then access the server using
  `ssh -i <pem file>  <instance-name>@<instance-ip>`

Then, I tried to ssh from my second machine.  I create a key pair again, and I do the same:  Save the pem file in a known location, make sure that the permissions are `chmod 400`, and then I try to connect as before:

`ssh -i <new path to pem file>  <instance-name>@<instance-ip>`

However, I consistently get a `connection timed out` error.

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <IP> [<IP>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <IP> port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Operation timed out
```

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html) but to no avail.

Here is a screen shot of the inbound rules:
[image: inbound rules]

In CIDR notation, this means all networks.

What is the issue and how do I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: inspect the output of: ssh -vvv -i <new path to pem file>  <instance-name>@<instance-ip>

Comment: I did try that more verbose output.  I've updated my question.  thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Connection timed out indicates that SSH cannot open a connection the remote system at all, thus it is not a file permission issue. Can you do `nc -v -z <instance-ip> 22` and connect successfully? If not, check that the security group for your EC2 instance allows port 22 from your second machine.

Comment: Yep, this timed out:  `ec2-<IP>.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [<IP>] 22 (ssh): Operation timed out`  So you think it's a port issue?

Comment: Check your EC2 security group and make sure that port 22 is allowed from your second machine. E.g., run `curl icanhazip.com` from the second machine, and make sure that IP is allowed for port 22 in the security group.

Comment: Under inbound connections, it lists port 22 under "port range" .  So, I think that the instance allows port 22.  It also allows ALL ports for outbound connections.

Comment: Does it allow port 22 for all IP addresses? post a screenshot of the incoming rules for your security group. Also check that no iptables rules are present on your instance, and make sure that you can make outbound connections on port 22 from your second machine.

Comment: I updated my question.  in CIDR notation, it shows that it should be allowing inbound connections from all IP addresses.  My machine seems to allow outbound connections on port 22.  I tried `nc -v <website> 22` and it connects no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If security groups are configured correctly, the next possible culprit is a firewall. You could have a firewall running on the remote machine, or a client side firewall, running either on your local machine or in a corporate network (this is more common than you think)

Try to ssh to the first machine, and from there ssh to the second one. If this fails, the second machine is probably misconfigured. If it succeeds, a firewall is probably at fault.